# Where does one go to find a JQuery programmer?

Tags: jquery

I write server code but have little to almost no JQ experience. I have a project that I'm working on right now that requires a small amount of JQuery. Can someone tell me where I can find someone that really, truly knows their stuff that might be looking to make a few extra bucks for the holiday season?

I'm working on a POS that requires a keypad as well as updating a div for inventory entered. This module should also handle the simple subtraction, addition as well as the calculation of duplicate items.

Thanks.

Comment: I hear John Resig is pretty hot on this jQuery stuff.  http://ejohn.org/

Comment: lol.. Yeah, he could certainly name his price too, couldn't he. I wish I had his knowledge. :)

Comment: Just for the record, I went to Resig's site and he states that he's not looking for work right now. Must not be affected by our economy. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.authenticjobs.com/
And I would rather buy jQuery: Novice to Ninja :)

Comment: tbleckert, thanks for the link. It looks promising.

Comment: It sure wouldn't hurt to have a book on hand. I'll pick it up the next time I'm out.

Answer (score 2):

Just buy "jQuery in Action" and get on with it.

Comment: A book? You want me to read a book? :) I've got to "get on with" the project and have loads of other stuff I need to focus on. I wish I had the time.

Comment: I didn't say anything about reading it!